# How to find quantization noise in my simulation?

Tags: matlab, noise, snr

For college we have to make simple exercise in simulink (matlab). (since my professor is not familiar with simulink, he can't help).

The question itself is, **how can I simulate the SNR when uniform quantization is used**. To illustrate this: [image]

Because of this quantization there is noise. I need to display this noise. How do i do this?

Additional information: 10 bit quantization. The source has to be 40db.

I know i can get the quantization error when I subtract the output from the input but i do not know how to get the quantization noise.

Comment: The quantization error is the quantization noise.  It is two different terms for the same thing.

Comment: I've read this too on wikipedia but the professor said that subtracting the 2 signals to get to get the noise was wrong ...

Comment: Hmm.  I think either you misunderstood the professor, or he was wrong.

Comment: @JimClay: could you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @MartinThompson Done.

Comment: It's really quantization *distortion*...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quantization error is the quantization noise. It is two different terms for the same thing.